# How to filter group by result in google sheet sql

Tags: filter, group-by, google-sheets, google-query-language

How to filter the group by result in google sheet like **'having'** in SQL

```
=QUERY(A2:D996,"select B, sum(C), Sum(D), (sum(C)-Sum(D)) where (D>0 Or C>0) group by B **having sum(C)-Sum(D)>0** label B 'Name', sum(C) 'Credit', sum(D) 'Debit', (sum(C)-Sum(D)) 'Balance'")
```

Answer (score 2):

`Having` is not an option, try `query` inside another `query`.